# Unable to retrieve query plan of running query because of blocking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I am trying to troubleshoot a long running query in a stored procedure that around once every month randomly runs for ever and never finishes.  Probably some plan caching issue.  But the problem is that I am unable to retrieve the query plan because of blocking in tempdb while the query is running.  I am using the below dmv's to try to retrieve the query plan

```
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2    
cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) s3
where object_name ( s2.objectid, s2.dbid) = 'sp_name'  
ORDER BY statement_start_offset
```

The above query to retrieve the plan gets blocked by the long running  problem query because the above query needs a schema S lock on an object on tempdb.  They long running query queries and updates a temp table and has option recompile on it.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Could you add a reproducable example? When I create a procdure that inserts, updates and selects from a temporary table, all with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` I can get the query plan using above query.

Comment: I can try, but its a reporting query that joins a couple of big tables and runs for 10 mins normally.  Did you try to retrieve the query plan while the query is running?

Comment: If possible, I wouldn't rely on plan from the cache to troubleshoot performances, since they're cached pre-execution. If not possible, I guess you could try and setup an extended events session to capture the compiled plan but be aware this is an expensive option.(either `sqlserver.query_post_execution_showplan` for actual query plans, or `sqlserver.query_post_compilation_showplan` for cached ones)

Answer (score 2):

Try flipping this predicate from

```
where object_name ( s2.objectid, s2.dbid) = 'sp_name'
```

to something like

```
where object_id = object_id('sp_name')
```

You might get a simpler plan that aviods whatever resource is blocked in TempDb.

Answer (score -3):

could you try this query:

```
SELECT 
    blocker.[spid],
    blocker.[Database],
    blocker.[Login],
    blocker.[Hostname],
--  blocker.[HostPID],
--  blocker.[ProgramName],
    blocker.[LastWaitType],
    blocker.[Blocker],
    blocker.[Command] AS [BlockerCommand],
    blocker.[SQL_Text] AS [Blocker_SQL_Text],
    blocker.[QueryPlan] AS [Blocker_Query_Plan],
    spr.[spid],
    RTRIM(spr.[loginame]) AS [Login],
--  DB_NAME(spr.[dbid]) AS [Database],
    RTRIM(spr.[hostname]) AS [Hostname],
--  spr.[hostprocess] AS [HostPID],
--  RTRIM(spr.[program_name]) AS [ProgramName],
    RTRIM(spr.[lastwaittype]) AS [LastWaitType],
    spr.[blocked] AS [Blocker],
    spr.[cmd] AS [BlockedCommand],
    EST.[text] AS [Blocked_SQL_Text],
    blocker.[KillCommand] AS [BlockerKillCommand]
FROM [master].[dbo].[sysprocesses] spr
    JOIN [master].[sys].[dm_exec_connections] dc ON spr.[spid] = dc.[session_id]
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dc.[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS EST
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            spr.[spid],
            DB_NAME(spr.[dbid]) AS [Database],
            RTRIM(spr.[loginame]) AS [Login],
            RTRIM(spr.[hostname]) AS [Hostname],
--          spr.[hostprocess] AS [HostPID],
--          RTRIM(spr.[program_name]) AS [ProgramName],
            RTRIM(spr.[lastwaittype]) AS [LastWaitType],
            spr.[blocked] AS [Blocker],
            spr.[cmd] AS [Command],
            EST.[text] AS [SQL_Text],
            EQP.[query_plan] AS [QueryPlan],
            'kill ' + CAST(spr.[spid] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [KillCommand]
        FROM [master].[dbo].[sysprocesses] spr
            JOIN [master].[sys].[dm_exec_connections] dc ON spr.[spid] = dc.[session_id]
            LEFT JOIN [master].[sys].[dm_exec_query_stats] AS EQS ON dc.[most_recent_sql_handle] = EQS.[sql_handle]
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dc.[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS EST 
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(EQS.[plan_handle]) AS EQP ) AS blocker ON spr.[blocked] = blocker.[spid]
WHERE spr.[blocked] <> 0
--AND blocker.Blocker = 0       -- Only Running Blockers
```